# Erro: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details

Tags: c#, entity-framework

O seguinte erro ocorre quando tento inserir dados no sistema: *Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details*. Acontece que o erro acontece quando ele chega na seguinte linha: `db.SaveChanges();`, sem contar que ele nem reconhece essa linha: `await db.SaveChangesAsync();`
Segue código:

```
private async void metroTile5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (frm_AddUsuario addUsuario = new frm_AddUsuario(new cad_usuario()))
            {
                if (addUsuario.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        cadusuarioBindingSource.Add(addUsuario.cadUsuarioUsuarioInfo);
                        db.cad_usuario.Add(addUsuario.cadUsuarioUsuarioInfo);
                       // await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Mensagem", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Alguém tem ideia de como resolvo esse problema?
Obrigada!

Comment: Poderia atualizar a pergunta com a mensagem dentro de  EntityValidationErrors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta mensagem indica que há erros de validação das entidades. Acrescente este trecho no código para identificar os erros de validação.

```
try
{
    // seu código...
    db.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
{
    foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Entidade do tipo \"{0}\" com estado \"{1}\" tem os seguintes erros de validação:",
            eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
        foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("- Propriedade: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Oi! Ele dá erro no throw: An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' occurred in GTR_2.0.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Comment: Alterei o Console por Debug.WriteLine, altere isso no código também. Sim, na verdade é o Throw que dispara o erro. Mas antes disso, o bloco `catch` capturou o erro causado no `db.SaveChanges()` . Verifique na janela output, pois as linhas `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` vão dar os detalhes do erro.

Comment: Caso a janela de Output não esteja aparecendo no momento do debug vá no menu _View_ do visual studio e selecione a opção _output_

Comment: Deu certo, agora ele mostra o erro: "Entidade do tipo "cad_usuario" com estado "Added" tem os seguintes erros de validação:
- Propriedade: "Senha_Usuario", Error: "O campo Senha_Usuario é obrigatório." " Mas é estranho porque eu preencho o textbox com a senha. O que será que pode ser?

Comment: Verifique em momento de debug o valor do objeto `addUsuario.cadUsuarioUsuarioInfo` e suas propriedades. As propriedades obrigatórias devem estar preenchidas

Comment: Eu verifiquei enquanto está debugando que todos os campos recebem valor, menos o da senha_usuario. Mas não sei onde arrumo isso. Há outras propriedades que devem ser verificadas?

Comment: Qual é o tipo de dado deste campo? Tente Forçar manualmente um valor em tempo de debug para ver qual é o comportamento.

Comment: Troquei pra varchar pra testar, mas estava char. Forcei durante o debug e ele foi normalmente, nenhum erro, e salvou no db.

Comment: Se passando "na mão" deu certo, verifique novamente como a sua entidade está sendo carregada, e se for pertinente, os mapeamentos (mapping) das entidades.

Comment: ó, deu certo aqui, comecei o projeto do 0 e funcionou. acho que ele é doido. ou eu troquei alguma coisa que não devia e doida sou eu. Muito obrigada de verdade!